# Discord.py Bot Reactions in DMs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot that I want to code to do the following things:

1. When a user types the command, the bot should send the user a DM
2. Then, it should add reactions to this message (A thumbs up and thumbs down)
3. Finally, it should wait for the user to react with one of those reactions.

Now based on the docs and previous projects, I came up with this function for adding reactions:

```py
async def get_reacts(user, client, message, emojis, timeout=None):
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    try:
        def check(reaction, reactor):
            return reactor.id == user.id and reaction.emoji in emojis
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, timeout=timeout)
        return reaction.emoji
    except:
        pass
```

This code works perfectly when in a server, but when the message is in a DM, it does something peculiar. First, it doesn't detect the user reactions at all. When I put a print statement  within the check function, it told me that it parsed one reaction, and that reaction was the bot itself reacting with the thumbs down. When I reacted to the message, the check function was never called.

I saw some other solutions used a Cog listener to go through all added reactions, and use a global list of messages. However, this won't work for my bot as everything it does is in one command. Additionally, it takes up a lot of memory. This is why I went with the `client.wait_for` approach instead.

Is there a problem with using `client.wait_for` in DMs? Should I use Cog listeners instead? Or is it a problem with my code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Intents enabled: None (Do I need an intent to check DM reactions?)

**EDIT 2:**
Added default intents, still the same issue

**EDIT 3:**
How I am using the `get_reacts` function:

```py
msg = await context.author.send("Message")
reaction = await get_reacts(context.author, self.client, msg, ["", ""])
```

Comment: What intents have you enabled? Could you also add that to the question please

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

In order to receive reactions event in DM from users you need to enable the `members` intent.

So the only thing you need to do is create your default intent and then set the `members` value to True :

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

## Explanation

Op was asking for clarification so here it is.

If you take a look at the `discord.Intents.default()` code :

```
@classmethod
def default(cls):
    self = cls.all()
    self.presences = False
    self.members = False
    return self
```

You can see it does two things :

- Generate intents for everything (using its own discord.Intents.all())
- From those intents, remove the one corresponding to `presence` and `members`

So the assumptions of op :

> This makes me think that maybe dm_reactions and reactions are not included in default intents

is not true. Because only presence and members are removed, all the other ones are in it.

Now, turns out even with `dm_reactions`, `reactions`, and `dm_messages` on, you still need to have the `members` on. So that is what is happenning in the solution.

And as OP pointed out, it does work with `discord.Intents.all()` because, in this case, the `member` intent is enabled.

Comment: Wow, that explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need intents. `dm_reactions` and `reactions` (It shouldn't work without them). Easiest for you would be to simply enable default intents

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Comment: I did that... but there's no change. It still doesn't recognize my reactions and only recognizes the bot reacting with thumbs down.

Comment: Well then there's something wrong in the check func

Comment: Do you know what's the issue?

Comment: Nope, you're not exactly showing how you use the `get_reacts` func

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Łukasz's answer, I tried some experimentation, and found that using `discord.Intents.all()` worked, but not `discord.Intents.default()`. This makes me think that maybe `dm_reactions` and `reactions` are not included in default intents, but *are* included in all intents? Any clarification on this is still appreciated, as I just started learning discord.py a few months ago.