# discord.py wait_for('reaction_add') functioning differently with direct messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My goal is to have the bot react to it's own message and then send a reply in that channel if the user who sent the original command reacts as well. Right now the function works if the command is sent in a server channel, but if sent as a direct message to the bot, it doesn't wait for your reaction. By printing the values of `user.id` and `ctx.author.id` during the check, I noticed that the bot checks it's own reaction sometimes (`user.id` returns the bot's id). I'm not sure if this is related because it waits for a reaction from the correct user in server channels regardless.

API Documentation for [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) and [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)

I'd like this function to work in servers and direct messages to the bot, am I missing something? Thanks!

```
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send(f'Hi {ctx.author.mention}')
    await msg.add_reaction('✅')

    def check(reaction, user):
        print(user.id, ctx.author.id)
        return reaction.message.id == msg.id and user.id == ctx.author.id and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        await ctx.send('success')
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you put the code that you're using to wait for the reaction in DMs?

Comment: thanks for the formatting help - it's there in the hello function under try:
reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0, check=check)

Comment: You're waiting till the person that invoked the command reacts to the message sent, if I react to a random message (e.g in DMs) it will not work, it must be the one the bot sent.

Comment: Not a random message, invoking the command in DMs, and reacting to the message the bot replies with and reacts to.

Comment: It works for me, what intents have you enabled?

Comment: It replies with 'success' in DMs for you as well? Even setting intents.reactions to True in the code doesn't change that it only works when invoking in servers for me.

Answer (score 2):

It was an intents issue after all, same permission issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628327/discord-py-bot-reactions-in-dms) post.
After `intents = discord.Intents.default()` you also need to enable server members privileged intent for your application [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and set `intents.members = True` in your code to give a bot the required permissions for this to work in DMs

Answer (score 0):

you can check the reactionary id

```
    def check(reaction, user):
        # let the user id str 
        print(str(reaction.author.id), str(ctx.author.id))
        return reaction.message.id == msg.id and reaction.author.id == ctx.author.id and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

    try:
        # wait for the reactions
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as error:
        pass
    else:
        # except an error
        await ctx.send('success')
```