# wait_for() from discord.py don't work in dm

Tags: python, discord.py

This code works in server channels, but does not work in private messages of users. Is there an alternative feature for private messages?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```

I found some problems similar to mine and rewrote the code, but it didn't help:

[discord.py wait_for('reaction_add') functioning differently with direct messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115501/discord-py-wait-forreaction-add-functioning-differently-with-direct-messages)

[Discord.py Bot Reactions in DMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628327/discord-py-bot-reactions-in-dms)

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        
        msg = await message.channel.send(f'Hi {message.author.mention}')
        await msg.add_reaction('✅')

        def check(reaction, user):
            print(user.id, message.author.id)
            return reaction.message.id == msg.id and user.id == message.author.id and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send('success')

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Why are you importing the intents that way? Can you please show us the part where you defined your `client`? The intents must be at the beginning of the code and then "imported" with `client = [...]`.

Comment: Didn't figure out how I can import intents using client = [...].

Comment: `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making an `intents` variable doesn't make your bot use it.

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```